# Moodle external DB authentication with MSSQL from windowsMembership function

Tags: php, asp.net-membership, moodle

I am using Moodle and integrating it with a newly developed ASP.NET application which uses MemberShip function..... 
I have tried with both MD5 hash,SHA-1 hash aswell... 
When I try with text as password foramt it works.. feels like there is some problem with encoding and decoding... help will be much appreciated....

I have the userName and password created from membership tables and created a view and trying to access this from my moodle... Rows are there for the userName and password and I am not able to access it

Edit :
When I try to debug this, i could see the way password stored in MSSQL is different than what moodle sends in query.. Please find the php logs below...

please help me guys...

**Password stored in MSSQL**

```
uMg8WgxqP+mB3hzcwbeAPqHnty4=                                                                                                     danielmoses
```

**Log when the hashing is configured as SHA-1 in external db settings page in moodle**

```
[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] sqlsrv_configure: SQLSTATE = IMSSP
[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] sqlsrv_configure: error code = -14
[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] sqlsrv_configure: message = An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_configure.
[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] <hr>connecting... hostname: localhost params: array (
'Database' => 'kpadb',
'UID' => 'sa1',
'PWD' => 'password',
)
**[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] <hr>running query: 'SELECT *
FROM MoodleAuthentication
WHERE UserName = \'danielmoses\'
AND Password = \'58cb4e2f82599535955e97a110eee6f429cd666d\''<hr>input array: false<hr>result: NULL**
[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] (before) ADODB_COUNTRECS: 1 _numOfRows: -1 _numOfFields: -1
[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] (after) _numOfRows: -1 _numOfFields: 2
[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] _fetch()
[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] fetch mode: assoc
[16-Mar-2014 08:47:40 UTC] <hr>after _fetch, fields: <pre> backtrace: <pre align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <font face="Courier New,Courier">ADORecordset_mssqlnative._fetch()</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 2989, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\lib\adodb\adodb.inc.php">adodb.inc.php</a></font>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <font face="Courier New,Courier">ADORecordSet.Init()</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 1086, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\lib\adodb\adodb.inc.php">adodb.inc.php</a></font>
&nbsp; &nbsp; <font face="Courier New,Courier">ADOConnection._Execute(SELECT * FROM MoodleAuthentication WHERE UserName = '..., false)</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 1044, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\lib\adodb\adodb.inc.php">adodb.inc.php</a></font>
&nbsp; <font face="Courier New,Courier">ADOConnection.Execute(SELECT * FROM MoodleAuthentication WHERE UserName = '...)</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 117, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\auth\db\auth.php">auth.php</a></font>
<font face="Courier New,Courier">auth_plugin_db.user_login(danielmoses, Dan@1234)</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 4393, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\lib\moodlelib.php">moodlelib.php</a></font>
<font face="Courier New,Courier">authenticate_user_login(danielmoses, Dan@1234)</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 140, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\login\index.php">index.php</a></font>
</pre>
```

**Log when the hashing is configured as MD-5 in external db settings page in moodle**

```
[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] sqlsrv_configure: SQLSTATE = IMSSP
[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] sqlsrv_configure: error code = -14
[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] sqlsrv_configure: message = An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_configure.
[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] <hr>connecting... hostname: localhost params: array (
'Database' => 'kpadb',
'UID' => 'sa1',
'PWD' => 'password',
)
**[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] <hr>running query: 'SELECT *
FROM MoodleAuthentication
WHERE UserName = \'danielmoses\'
AND Password = \'4518af96674e69424360f61f1f6d129c\''<hr>input array: false<hr>result: NULL**
[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] (before) ADODB_COUNTRECS: 1 _numOfRows: -1 _numOfFields: -1
[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] (after) _numOfRows: -1 _numOfFields: 2
[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] _fetch()
[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] fetch mode: assoc
[16-Mar-2014 08:56:37 UTC] <hr>after _fetch, fields: <pre> backtrace: <pre align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <font face="Courier New,Courier">ADORecordset_mssqlnative._fetch()</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 2989, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\lib\adodb\adodb.inc.php">adodb.inc.php</a></font>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <font face="Courier New,Courier">ADORecordSet.Init()</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 1086, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\lib\adodb\adodb.inc.php">adodb.inc.php</a></font>
&nbsp; &nbsp; <font face="Courier New,Courier">ADOConnection._Execute(SELECT * FROM MoodleAuthentication WHERE UserName = '..., false)</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 1044, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\lib\adodb\adodb.inc.php">adodb.inc.php</a></font>
&nbsp; <font face="Courier New,Courier">ADOConnection.Execute(SELECT * FROM MoodleAuthentication WHERE UserName = '...)</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 117, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\auth\db\auth.php">auth.php</a></font>
<font face="Courier New,Courier">auth_plugin_db.user_login(danielmoses, Dan@1234)</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 4393, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\lib\moodlelib.php">moodlelib.php</a></font>
<font face="Courier New,Courier">authenticate_user_login(danielmoses, Dan@1234)</font><font color=#808080 size=-1> % line 140, file: <a href="file:/C:\inetpub\wwwroot\moodle\login\index.php">index.php</a></font>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably the password salting

http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Password_salting

Although I would recommend using the external database authentication to synchronise your users from the asp.net system

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/External_database_authentication

Comment: Thanks Russell for your reply.. Actually I am using External DB authentication... I have my fields configured and you can see them in the screenshot... I am not sure where the cron job setting is done..even with this setting it is not working.. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84286294/2014-03-16_09-35-30.png this is the settings that I use... My php version is 5.3.28 .. which is lesser than 5.3.7 as mentioned in password salting... please advise.. thanks for your time and effort..

Comment: Sorry PHP version is fine as I have updated version than 5.3.7

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MSSQL - but just had a look at how the MD5 is created. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx - there are some comments saying the MD5 hash is computed differently for different column types. Just wondering if that is the problem. Can you check that the data type for mdl_user.password is the same as MoodleAuthentication.Password. Also does SELECT HASHBYTES('md5', 'passwordtext') give the same result as 'uMg8WgxqP+mB3hzcwbeAPqHnty4= '?

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient, ancient question but for anyone that stumbles across it, this is working PHP code to get the value stored in the password hash field:

```
$storedHash = base64_encode( sha1(base64_decode($passwordsalt) . mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'), true) )
```

`$password` is the unencrypted password.

`$passwordsalt` is the aspnet_Membership PasswordSalt field.

`$storedHash` should match the value stored in the aspnet_Membership Password field.